# Как на php 1000 вывести словом 1 тыс

Tags: php

Подскажите как вывести вместо трех нулей в конце слово ( **тыс.** ) например если выводится **2000** мне нужно чтобы было **2 тыс.** ну а если **15000** тогда **15 тыс**. может какую-то функцию подскажете на php.

Comment: А что выводить, если 2001?

Comment: Если выводит 2001 тогда округлить до 2 тыс. а если выводит 2100 тогда 2 тыс. 100

Comment: Отлично, а с какого момента перестать округлять?

Comment: Скрипт должен работать до 1 000 000 извиняюсь может я неправильно объяснил

Comment: @Muson, имелось ввиду — как выводить 2002, 2010, 2099?

Comment: Никаких функций для этого нет, напишите её самстоятельно.

Comment: 2002, 2010, 2099 выводить не нужно просто 2 тыс. то есть округлить до 2 тыс.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например, так:

```
$summa = 2002;
$tys = floor($summa / 1000);
$ostatok = $summa % 1000;
$itogo = $tys.' тыс. '.$ostatok;
```

Answer (score 1):

Сервака не было под рукой, вот на js
Перевести - одна минута.

```js
$('#ok').click(function() {
     var a = $('#input').val();
     var output = "";
     if (a == 1000000) {
       output = '1 млн руб';
     } else if (a < 1000) {
       output = a + 'руб';
     } else if (a < 1000000) {
       output = parseInt(a / 1000) + ' тыс ' + a % 1000 + 'руб';
     } else {
       output = "";
     }
     $('#output').text(output);
   });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="input">
<input type="button" value="ok" id="ok">
<hr>
<p id="output"></p>
```

Если надо округлить, тогда в третьем условии оставь только
`output = parseInt(a / 1000) + ' тыс '`

Answer (score 1):

можно начать с пакета [number_words](https://pear.php.net/package/Numbers_Words) и внести в него необходимые правки.

в *debian-основных* дистрибутивах он находится в пакете `php-numbers-words`:

```
$ sudo apt-get install php-numbers-words
```

пример «однострочника»:

```
$ php -r 'require_once("Numbers/Words/lang.ru.php");
  $obj = new Numbers_Words_ru;
  print $obj->_toWords(round(999/100)*100) . "\n";
  print $obj->_toWords(round(1555/100)*100) . "\n";
  print $obj->_toWords(round(1101/100)*100) . "\n";' | iconv -f cp1251
одна тысяча 
одна тысяча шестьсот 
одна тысяча сто
```